# Chrome extensions: make chrome.tabs.query() synchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I am currently using this code:

```
url = "unknown";
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function(tabs) {
    console.log(tabs); //test, prints one-element array as expected
    url = tabs[0].url;
});
$("#url_div").html(url);
```

to get current URL, but `chrome.tabs.query()` is *asynchronous*, how can I make it synchronous? (i.e. add `asynch: false` somewhere)

I know I could set the URL *inside* the query, or call another function from there, but best would be (example is simplifed) if it wasnt asynch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless there is some hidden functionality in the query function this is not possible. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query