# Trouble with variable scope in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scope

I'm writing a Chrome Extension. I have the following piece of code.

```
function getCurrentTab() {
  var r;
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active:true,
    currentWindow:true
  },function (tabs) {
    r=tabs[0];
    console.log(r);
  });
  return r;
}

console.log(getCurrentTab());
```

I expect this function to return the active tab. Unfortunately the attribution inside the callback function doesn't affect r from the parent function `getCurrentTab` and I can't figure out why is that.

At the moment this code writes to console:

```
undefined
Object {active: true, height: 954, highlighted: true, id: 16, incognito: false…}
```

Desired result would be:

```
Object {active: true, height: 954, highlighted: true, id: 16, incognito: false…}
Object {active: true, height: 954, highlighted: true, id: 16, incognito: false…}
```

Comment: The callback you are passing to the query function is asynchronous, so the assigment isn't happening until after getCurrentTab has returned.

Comment: Pass a callback function to the getCurrentTab method that is called in the query callback, and takes 'r' as an argument.

Comment: @rsanchez - I don't want to move my logic in the callback function, like the solution suggested in the linked question.

Comment: @Jack Newcombe - Sorry, I don't understand. Would you mind giving an example? Thanks

Comment: Sure I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this without using a callback function unless a synchronous version of query is provided (which is unlikely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the callback for the query function is asynchronous, you need to provide a callback function to the getCurrentTab function and do your operations in there:

```
function getCurrentTab(callback) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active:true,
        currentWindow:true
    }, function (tabs) {
        callback(tabs[0]);
    });
}

getCurrentTab(function(r){
    console.log(r);
    // ... other operations using current tab ...
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. I'd prefer it if it were possible to avoid using any callbacks. Thanks.

Comment: Evidence suggests that you can't avoid it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748101/chrome-extensions-make-chrome-tabs-query-synchronous

Comment: Seems that way and it sucks :(

Comment: If you're worried about control flow, you could consider using promises: https://github.com/bellbind/using-promise-q/